# R Shiny: conditionalPanel not working if used several widgets

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Conditional pannel doesn't show the message "Loading..." in my shiny app. Message must appear when all widgets have been pressed.

```
sidebarPanel(id="sidebar",
                 textInput("id1", "Write word 1:"),
                 textInput("id2", "Write word 2:"),
                 selectInput("line", "Select:",
                             c("Line1"=1,
                               "Line2"=2,
                               "Line3"=3)),
                 dateRangeInput("dateRange",
                                label = "Select a date range:", start = as.character(Sys.Date()-1), end = as.character(Sys.Date()),
                 actionButton("update", "OK"),
                 p("Press OK to update inputs"),
                 conditionalPanel(condition="input.id1>0 && input.id2>0 &&  input.line>0 && input.dateRange>0 && input.update>0",
                                 tags$div("Loading...",id="loadmessage"))
                 )
```

I think the condition is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with compare `numeric` and `character` in js

You need to use 0 only for numerict results ( actionButton and selectInput in your example)

You need such condition `input.id1>'' && input.id2>'' &&  input.line>0&& input.dateRange>'' && input.update>0`